# DNS redirection does not remember path/ parameters apache

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain, redirect

I just registered a domain name with fasthosts to redirect a URL to my server IP, and currently whenever I make a request, the domain abandons the full path/ parameters of the request and just redirects to the server root.

For example:

I want this request:

```
http://www.example.com/scripts/file?param1=hello&param2=goodbye
```

to redirect to something like this:

```
http://XX.XX.XX.XXX/scripts/file?param1=hello&param2=goodbye
```

However it currently redirects to just this, abandoning the parameters:
    http://XX.XX.XX.XXX/

My apache sites-available looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ExtFilterDefine gzip mode=output cmd=/bin/gzip
    DocumentRoot /root/osm-3s_v0.7.4/html


    ScriptAlias /api/ /var/www/osm/cgi-bin/


    # This specifies some directives specific to the directory: [YOUR_EXEC_DIR]/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/var/www/osm/cgi-bin/">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            #SetOutputFilter gzip
            #Header set Content-Encoding gzip
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Does anybody know what's wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: The Apache config has no apparent role in the redirect. It is being handled by either a CGI script or by Fasthost, neither of which would be particularly on-topic for here.

Comment: Your question is confusingly worded and contains what appear to me to be entirely unrelated red herrings about DNS.

Answer (score 1):

Ditch the HTTP redirect (its NOT a "DNS redirect", just FYI). Get an A record pointing to your IP. Add www.example.com as a ServerAlias in your apache vhost.